# Bedeutung von "Leicht" in "leicht fettendes Haar"

Tags: meaning, synonym

Auf vielen Shampoos steht "Für leicht fettendes Haar". Ist hier das "leicht" als Synonym für "wenig/gering fettendes Haar" zu verstehen (wie in "ein leichter Glanz"), oder als Synonym für "schnell fettendes Haar" (wie in "er gerät leicht in Schwierigkeiten")?

Gibt es einen Grund, warum nur eine der Interpretationen richtig ist?

Comment: In der Praxis ist es stets "schnell fettendes Haar", ich sehe aber nichts das *sprachlich* gegen "kaum fettendes Haar" spräche!

Comment: Frage gefällt mir!

Comment: Auch eine doppelte Bedeutung von leicht: "Meine Hand tut mir leicht weh" -> Tut die Hand nur ein wenig weh, oder ist es einfach, der Hand weh zu tun? Schwer zu sagen.

Comment: Gute Frage. Eine ähnliche Zweideutigkeit ist mir in diesem Zusammenhang auch schon aufgefallen: Es gibt "Zahncreme für strahlend weiße Zähne" und "Shampoo für leicht fettendes Haar". Nun, wer will denn schon letzteres? (Egal, wie es hier genau gemeint ist)

Comment: Achso, das ist gar nicht »wenig fettendes Haar«? Wieder was gelernt …

Comment: Ergebnisse einer kurzen Schnelluntersuchung auf den Webseiten der Hersteller: "Schauma" gibt's nur für *schnell* fettendes Haar, "Schwarzkopf kennt nur *Anti-Fett-Shampoo*, "Nivea" kennt tatsächlich *leicht fettendes Haar* (aber kein *stark* noch sonstwie anders fettendes, nur noch *trockenes*), und dann hat mich die Lust verlassen... Aber wir haben herausgefunden, womit sich @subrunner die Haare wäscht...

Answer (score 4):

Eigentlich sehe ich keinen Grund, warum eine der beiden Bedeutungen vorzuziehen wäre - Ohne Kontext betrachtet, sind beide für mich absolut gleichwertig und damit mißverständlich.

Der Kontext ist: "Was steht denn auf der anderen Flasche?" - Und da steht meistens "Für trockenes und sprödes Haar". Eine "für sehr fettendes Haar" (als Gegenstück der "wenig/gering"-Bedeutung) gibt es m.W. im Laden nicht, ich habe zumindestens noch keine gefunden. Der arme Tropf mit den fettigen Haaren wird also schon das Richtige nehmen und die Bedeutung wird wohl "schnell fettendes Haar" sei.

Answer (score 2):

Da es im Drogeriemarkt meines Vertrauens neben "Shampoo für leicht fettendes Haar" auch "Shampoo für stark fettendes Haar" gibt, halte ich die erste Bedeutung (leicht = wenig) für die zutreffende.
Ohne diese Kontextinformation würde ich die Bezeichnung als uneindeutig empfinden und eine/n Fachverkäufer/in konsultieren.

Comment: Mit "leicht" ist das so eine Sache… Ich stolpere immer über "pflegeleicht" (bei Wäsche). Gleiches Problem. Ist die nun leicht (=einfach) zu pflegen (im Sinne von anspruchslos) oder _darf_ man sie nur leicht (=vorsichtig) pflegen? Ich weiss aus Erfahrung, dass letzteres gemeint ist, aber es könnte genau so gut bedeuten, dass man sie kochen und auf ●●● bügeln darf.

Comment: Kann es sein dass sich die Bedeutung von der Herren- zur Damenabteilung umdreht? Denn, auf @tofros Tip hin habe ich nachgeschaut, und da sind tatsächlich nur Shampoos für "trockenes Haar" zu finden. Ich habe allerdings nur bei den Shampoos für Frauen geschaut, und auch da nicht komplett alles (die Auswahl beim dm ist zu groß).